# Object Factories

Tags: php, oop, factory

I'm a little overwhelmed by managing a complex php oop application. In the past I've used static methods for my 'utils' classes but I'm writing a new app and I want to code to the highest standard possible so I'm look to avoid them where possible. Maintain testability etc.

I've looked at dependency injection but I'm planning to create a 'library' (so-to-speak) of helper classes that I can drop in-and-out of projects without too much trouble. My problem with this is that, because I'll have maybe five or six of these, I don't really want to set up constructs in which the user needs to pass all of these objects in to.

My research has brought me to factories - and I've created such a beast but I really don't know if this is the right way to go about things. It goes a little something like this...

```
class Create {

private static $validation = null;
private static $helper = null;
private static $html = null;
private static $form = null;
public static $user = null;
public static $db = null;

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Initialize
// --------------------------------------------------------------

public static function load($object, $options, $dependencies = array('html', 'helper', 'db', 'user')) {

    // Create specified object (without constructor)
    // PHP version < 5.4
    $$object = self::createInstanceWithoutConstructor($object);

    // Inject specified options into new object
    foreach($dependencies as $dependency):
        if(is_null(self::$$dependency)): self::$$dependency = new $dependency; endif;
        $$object->$dependency = self::$$dependency;
    endforeach;

    // Now call the constructor
    // PHP version < 5.4
    if(method_exists($$object, '__construct')):
        $$object->__construct($options);
    endif;

    return $$object;

}

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Create Instance of Object Without Calling it's Constructor
// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Workaround for PHP version < 5.4
// This will be updated to use
// ReflectionClass::newInstanceWithoutConstructor
// when 5.4 is more freely supported
// --------------------------------------------------------------

private static function createInstanceWithoutConstructor($class) {

    $reflector = new ReflectionClass($class);
    $properties = $reflector->getProperties();
    $defaults = $reflector->getDefaultProperties();

    $serealized = "O:" . strlen($class) . ":\"$class\":".count($properties) .':{';
    foreach ($properties as $property){
        $name = $property->getName();
        if($property->isProtected()){
                $name = chr(0) . '*' .chr(0) .$name;
            } elseif($property->isPrivate()){
                $name = chr(0)  . $class.  chr(0).$name;
            }
            $serealized .= serialize($name);
            if(array_key_exists($property->getName(),$defaults) ){
                $serealized .= serialize($defaults[$property->getName()]);
            } else {
                $serealized .= serialize(null);
            }
        }
    $serealized .="}";

    return unserialize($serealized);

}

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Create User
// --------------------------------------------------------------

public static function User($options = array()) {

    $user = self::load(__FUNCTION__, $options);
    return $user;

}

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Create Page
// --------------------------------------------------------------

public static function Page($options = array()) {

    $page = self::load(__FUNCTION__, $options);
    return $page;

}

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Create Form
// --------------------------------------------------------------

public static function Form($name, $method = 'POST', $action = null, $attributes = array()) {

    // Check to see if form was submitted
    // If so, get form object, otherwise create new form object
    if(isset($_POST[$name])):
        $form = unserialize($_SESSION['formObj']);
        $form->errors = array();
        $form->rule = $form->rule;
        $form->labels = $form->labels;
        $form->errors = $form->errors;
    else:
        $form = self::load(__FUNCTION__, array(), array('html', 'validation'));
        $form->name = $name;
    endif;

    // Open the form
    $form->open($method, $action, $attributes);

    return $form;

}

}
```

So it has separate functions for creating various objects, there is a default selection passed in unless the dependencies are explicitly set.

Now, I'm really not sure if this is a good approach, from more research, I've gathered it may be a better idea to have one factory for each class that is responsible for creating objects in that class. Is that the more 'correct' way of approaching this? If so, should those factory methods (not sure if that's the right term?) just be statics that can be called anywhere or can they just be normal methods which creates the new objects and then pass them in? Will this also need to extend a 'Factory' class which holds the created objects?

Hope that all made sense, any and all help would be appreciated.

Yours,

Confused N00b.

Comment: Just a small hint: Classes whose names are verbs are either badly named or - most often - badly encapsulated. An action (verb) is not an object (noun).

Comment: If you have classes with too many dependencies, then it is a clear sign, that your class has too many responsibilities. Instead of adding some magic, you should instead try to fix those classes. Also, what is the point of that `$$object` thing? Why cannot you just call it `$instance`, since it is a local variable and it's name has no effect outside the function.

Comment: I don't think my classes have too many responsibilities, it's that I want my 'helper' classes to be easily available throughout the application. I'm just finding it difficult to allow while trying to avoid static classes.

As for $object - $instance would probably make more sense tbh. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your code and reading your post, I feel like you are over-complicating things.

You don't need to focus on what is the "correct" way to do something. The correct way to do something is the way that works best for your given scenario. Look at what you need to do, look ahead to the future (but not too far!!), and try to find a solution that isn't over-designed, but gives you room to grow.

I say not too far into the future because developers often tend to get too caught up in their design, trying to plan for every possible eventuality, and you end up with a monster that is impossible to maintain.

If a series of factory functions contained in a static class is working for you, and you don't foresee any major issues with this any time soon, why do you need to keep designing? One of the hardest things to learn to do is to walk the line between designing for the future, and just getting things done :)

Comment: I like this answer but I just have this feeling that I should be looking to learn this kind of pattern (this isn't just a hobby!). What works best for me would be to lose the factory but rely on static classes that can easily be dropped in to multiple projects without issue. That's more of a convenience and ease-of-use answer though. I'd prefer to nail down the factory pattern then decide but I'm still to find anything that really suggests what the correct thing to do is in a easy-to-understand manner.

Comment: Well, the only way to learn is make mistakes :) Do what you feel you need! However, know that there is no one correct way to implement a pattern, they are merely suggestions for solving complex problems. Use them for inspiration, but adapt them for your situation. If you are designing something to be portable, the only thing that really matters right now is the interface. Everything behind the interface can be easily changed later. Factories are convenient because they hide the details of creation from the caller behind a simpler interface, so it's easier to change it later.

Answer (score 0):

What you listed is looks like bad attempt to make Service Locator. It's sort of registry pattern.
Every class should have certain purpose.
So make ServiceLocator class and number of factory classes/methods to return instances. Then set them to ServiceLocator on application startup.